# kubectl reports namespace value required in manifest file

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

What is the issue with my manifest file?

```
cat manifests/node-exporter-clusterRoleBinding.yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: node-exporter
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: node-exporter
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: node-exporter

cat manifests/kube-state-metrics-clusterRoleBinding.yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: kube-state-metrics
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: kube-state-metrics
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: kube-state-metrics
```

If I apply these manifest with namespace I get an error as like below:

```
kubectl -f manifests/kube-state-metrics-clusterRoleBinding.yaml -n test-monitoring

The ClusterRoleBinding "node-exporter" is invalid: subjects[0].namespace: Required value

kubectl apply -f manifests/kube-state-metrics-clusterRoleBinding.yaml -n test-monitoring

The ClusterRoleBinding "kube-state-metrics" is invalid: subjects[0].namespace: Required value
```

Any issue with manifests files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a `ServiceAccount` is a namespaced object, you need to explicitly add the `namespace` of the `ServiceAccount` as:

```
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: kube-state-metrics
  namespace: <namespace-of-kube-state-metrics-serviceaccount>
```